# Find $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\ln(e^x+1)}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\ln(e^x+1)}{x}$$

due to Squeeze theorem and $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$ we have

$$1\leftarrow\frac{\ln(e^x+1)}{e^x}\leq \frac{\ln(e^x+1)}{x}$$

what can be the upper bound of this function, or is there better solution?

Comment: Are you sure about $-\infty$ ?

Comment: I should have the inequality reversely.....

Comment: Are you sure the problem is asked with $-\infty$ ? This is unlikely.

Comment: You are right @YvesDaoust. shame on me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider that
$$ \lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}\ln(e^x+1) = \ln\left(\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} e^x + 1\right)= \ln(1) = 0$$
and 
$$ \lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}\frac{1}{x}= 0$$
So your limit is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\ln(e^x+1)=x+\ln(1+e^{-x}).
$$

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need the Squeeze Theorem here. As $x\to-\infty$, $e^x\to0$, so the numerator in the limit turns into $\ln(0+1)=0$. Therefore,
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\ln(e^x+1)}{x}=\frac{0}{-\infty}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\to -\infty$. Since $\ln(e^x+1)\to\ln 1=0$ and $\frac{1}{x}\to 0$, the limit in question equals to zero.